# Not able to customize the view with Included Components in Java FX

Tags: javafx, javafx-8, scenebuilder

I've created one child component and and I included it in another parent component using `fx:include`.

The controllers for the parent and the child are instantiated well.
However, in the parent FXML, I have `GridPane` as the parent for the child fxml. The child fxml is added by default at (0, 0). When I want to change the view and put the child component inside a different row/column index using SceneBuilder, I am not able to drag the component into it.

I am only able to organize the components inside `VBox` which doesn't meet my needs.

Parent FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<fx:root maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
   <children>
      <fx:include source="test.fxml" />
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

Child FXML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<Label text="Label" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" />
```

Please try to see if you are able to play with the child view inside the parent view. For example, I am not able to put the child inside a grid view in some arbitrary place.

Comment: What is the root element of your custom component? Can you update your question with a minimum of code used ?

Comment: @BoHalim Hi, thanks for your comment. I have updated my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion with OP, I found that the OP actually wanted to have the GridPane in the parent fxml and he wanted to place the included fxml at a particular row and column index of the GridPane. By default the SceneBuilder adds the FXML to (0,0).

***This is currently not supported by the SceneBuilder.***

You can however edit the FXML directly and change the rowIndex and columnIndex in there.

**Parent.fxml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.GridPane?>

<GridPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.111" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <children>
        <fx:include source="child.fxml" GridPane.rowIndex="1" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
    </children>
</GridPane>
```

---

### Steps to include a FXML in SceneBuilder :

- Choose GridPane as the root layout

[image: Choose GridPane as the root layout]

- Go to "Include FXML"

[image: Include FXML]

- Choose FXML to include

[image: Choose FXML to include]

- FXML added to GridPane

[image: FXML added to GridPane]